# ¿Como cambiar el valor de una variable ya definida en CSS?

Tags: css

Hola tengo el siguiente problema y es que tengo varias variables de colores definidas en mi css, por ejemplo:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: rgba(74, 54, 251);
}
```

Y en un div tengo la propiedad boxshadow, para mostrar una sombra con el color que ya esta definido, por ejemplo:

```
.my-div{
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary);
}
```

Pero necesito cambiarle la opacidad. Normalmente el `rgba` admite cambiarle la opcidad de la siguiente manera:

```
.my-div{
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(74, 54, 251, .45);
}
```

Como se puede observar la el valor después de la ultima coma ya es la opacidad que tendrá ese color, pero como estoy utilizando una variable de css fija no encuentro manera de cambiarle la opacidad.

Solo tiene que ser la opacidad del boxshadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tengo la respuesta, primero declaro mi variable no como un rgba, sino como el valor de rbg:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: 74, 54, 251;
}
```

Para que pueda ser utilizada de manera dinámica lo que hice fue esto:

```
.my-div{
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(var(--color-primary), .45);
}
```

Así podre cambiar la opacidad de manera correcta

Answer (score 3):

Si declaramos una variable en la pseudoclase **`:root`**<sup>1</sup> esta será heredada a todos los elementos dependientes de este<sup>2</sup>.

Una posible opción es que declares a la misma variable pero en el selector del elemento donde quieres que incluya el canal alpha mas o menos así:

```html
<style>
  :root {
     --color-primary: rgba(74, 54, 251);
  }
  #elemento1 {
    --color-primary: rgba(74, 54, 251, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary);
  }
  #elemento2 {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary);
  }
</style>

<div id="elemento1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam libero facilis quibusdam, doloribus culpa! Nesciunt, provident. Ipsam similique tempora dolore excepturi, eligendi et, iure rerum, architecto possimus, incidunt tenetur qui!
</div>
<div id="elemento2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam libero facilis quibusdam, doloribus culpa! Nesciunt, provident. Ipsam similique tempora dolore excepturi, eligendi et, iure rerum, architecto possimus, incidunt tenetur qui!
</div>
```

Sin embargo si estamos hablando de variables, creo que haría mas sentido declarar las que sean necesarias para cada caso de uso, es decir:

- Una variable para declarar el color pero sin el canal alpha
- Otra variable para declarar el color pero esta que si incluya el canal alpha

De modo que según sean requeridas en tu desarrollo termines ocupando una u otra, quedando así:

```html
    <style>
      :root {
        --color-primary-s-alpha: rgba(74, 54, 251);
        --color-primary-c-alpha: rgba(74, 54, 251, 0.5);
      }
      #elemento1 {
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary-s-alpha);
      }
      #elemento2 {
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary-c-alpha);
      }
      #elemento3 {
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px var(--color-primary-s-alpha);
      }
    </style>
    
    <div id="elemento1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam libero facilis quibusdam, doloribus culpa! Nesciunt, provident. Ipsam similique tempora dolore excepturi, eligendi et, iure rerum, architecto possimus, incidunt tenetur qui!
    </div>
    <div id="elemento2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam libero facilis quibusdam, doloribus culpa! Nesciunt, provident. Ipsam similique tempora dolore excepturi, eligendi et, iure rerum, architecto possimus, incidunt tenetur qui!
    </div>
    <div id="elemento3">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam libero facilis quibusdam, doloribus culpa! Nesciunt, provident. Ipsam similique tempora dolore excepturi, eligendi et, iure rerum, architecto possimus, incidunt tenetur qui!
    </div>
```

**Referencia**

- <sup>1</sup>[pseudoclase `:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:root)
- <sup>2</sup>[CSS Variables sintax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#syntax)

Comment: El css que estoy trabajando es un poco libre para el usuario, ya que puede cambiar la paleta de colores definida. Lo quería hacer de esa manera para que al cambiar el color primario cambie junto la sombra, no estar cambiando los dos, ya que el usuario no sabrá mucho de para que es la sombra, etc.

Comment: @JosueMartinez es bueno que puntualices esos detalles, justo con eso no considero que esto responda a la duda expuesta, te pediriía por favor desmarques el aporte ya que no es propiamente la solución

Comment: @JosueMartinez y si gustas edita agregando eso que me explicas a ver si alguien mas se anima a responder

Comment: Respondí mi propia pregunta, muchas gracias al fin lo logre!

Comment: @JosueMartinez ingeniosa y muy funcional contarás con mi +1 y no olvides marcarla como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita

Answer (score 1):

Buenos puedes crear valores de configuración en tu CSS, en las variables no guardas valores validos de css si no valores para procesar después, con un ejemplo es mas fácil.

```
:root {
      --color-primary: rgba(var(--theme-color-primary), var(--theme-alpha-primary));
}
```

entonces la variable `--theme-color-primary` no debe contener un valor en la forma `rgb(#,#,#)` si no los números del color `#,#,#`.

```
:root {
      --theme-color-primary: 255,55,55;
      --color-primary: rgba(var(--theme-color-primary), var(--theme-alpha-primary));
}
```

Ahora te agrego un ejemplo de como se cambiarían los colores del tema, usando tanto css y javascript; he tenido que crear `ToRGB` para pasar de 'HEX' a 'RGB' y tambien `appendStyle` tomando de [aqui](https://dev.to/azettl/convert-hex-to-rgb-with-javascript-5h06) para cambiar el `:root`.

```js
function setTheme(){
  let primary = document.getElementById('color').value
  console.log(primary)
  config['--theme-color-primary'] =  primary.ToRGB().join(',')
  appendStyle()
}

String.prototype.ToRGB = function(){
    var aRgbHex = this.replace('#','').match(/.{1,2}/g);
    var aRgb = [
        parseInt(aRgbHex[0], 16),
        parseInt(aRgbHex[1], 16),
        parseInt(aRgbHex[2], 16)
    ];
    return aRgb;
}
 

var config = {
  '--theme-alpha-primary': .5,
  '--theme-color-primary': '74, 54, 251',
}

function appendStyle() {
  let css = "";
  for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(config)) {
    css += (key + ':' + value+';\n');
  }
  css = ':root { '+css+' }';
  style = document.createElement('STYLE');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}

appendStyle()
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<input type="color" id="color" oninput="setTheme()" onclick="setTheme()">
<button class="btn">boton</button>


<style>
:root {
    --color-primary: rgba(var(--theme-color-primary), var(--theme-alpha-primary));
}
.btn {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}
</style>
```